# If expression.nil? then expression else other expression

Tags: ruby

I find myself often seeing a pattern when I want to evaluate some expression, and if true give the result of the expression, or if false perform some other similar expression. For example

```
if hours.detect { |h| h.position > i && h.open == true }.nil?
  hours.detect { |h| h.position >= 0 && h.open == true }
else
  hours.detect { |h| h.position > i && h.open == true }
end
```

This code seems very redundant. Can someone suggest a more elegant way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know ruby very well but this does look like 3 full traversals of an array when you could do it in 1? Also why not store the first value?

Comment: Yes, it's unnecessary work, @Daniel, but not quite 3 full traversals.  If `detect` finds a true condition in the first line, it will stop looking and after `else` `detect` will do the very same thing, stopping at the same point (zero full traversals).  If `detect` does not find a true condition in the first line (one full traversal), the next line will be executed, which may or may not involve a full traversal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code:

```
hh = hours.select {|h| h.open == true }
hh.detect { |h| h.position > i } || hh.detect { |h| h.position >= 0 }
```

In most cases (when `h.open` returns a boolean value) it can be transformed into the following one:

```
hh = hours.select {|h| h.open }
hh.detect { |h| h.position > i } || hh.detect { |h| h.position >= 0 }
```

Comment: Minor note, if `h.open` can contain non-boolean values then `{|h| h.open}` will return more results than `{|h| h.open == true}`

Comment: I don't think that `h.open` will be non non-boolean. But fix it.

Comment: Awesome. This makes a lot of sense and works well in my use case.

Answer (score 0):

I would do as below :

```
hh_true = hours.select {|h| h.open == true }
prc = prc hh_true.detect { |h| h.position >= 0 }
hh_true.detect(prc) { |h| h.position > i }
```

One example to illustrate this :

```
ary = ['fooo','fooo','foo']
prc = proc {ary.find{|e| e.size == 3}}
ary.detect(prc){|e| e.size == 5}
# => "foo"
ary.detect(prc){|e| e.size == 4 }
# => "fooo"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first create a method

```
def detect_hours(i)
  hours.detect { |h| h.position > i && h.open }
end
```

then just use below

```
detect_hours(i) || detect_hours(0)
```

Comment: If you do it that way, you'll need to pass `hours` as a second argument.  Right now, it's an uninitialized local variable, resulting in an exception being thrown when the method is invoked.  You should have tested your code.  You've been naughty, and Santa will remember.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward solution is:

```
hours.detect { |h| h.position >  i && h.open == true } || \
hours.detect { |h| h.position >= 0 && h.open == true }
```

But is it the most efficient? At first glance, one would think not, that it is better to first `select` those `hours` for which `h.open == true`.  But recall that `detect` quits once it finds a true condition, which could be the first element of `hours` in the first block or the last element of `hours` in the second block.  Relative efficiency will depend on the data. If `h.position > i` is usually true, this may well be faster than first doing a `select`, which requires a complete traversal of `hours`.  If efficiency is important, one might test this, as well as the effect of reversing the two `&&`'ed conditions in each block.

Answer (score 0):

```
hours.sort! { |h1,h2|
  ((-1 if h1.open == false) || (1 if h1.position > i) || (0 if h1.position >= 0)) <=>
  ((-1 if h2.open == false) || (1 if h2.position > i) || (0 if h2.position >= 0))
}
hours[0] if hours[0].open
```

I think this works, but I'm not 100% sure. Basically, map `hours` to a number, sort those numbers, and it'll be the first element.

This is better if you don't expect to have any `h.position > i` cases, since you'll have to check the entire array anyway.

Alternatively, although I'm not sure on the syntax, use the `ifnone` feature in `detect`:

```
hours.find(lambda{hours.find{|h| h.open && h.position > 0}}){|h| h.open && h.position > i}
```

Answer (score 0):

`hours.detect { |h| h.position > i && h.open == true }` is repeated **exactly** twice. In many languages you can store it into some variable:

```
var1 = hours.detect { |h| h.position > i && h.open == true }
```

then in your if, you can substitute it:

```
if var1.nil?
  hours.detect { |h| h.position >= 0 && h.open == true }
else
  var1
end
```

You can get rid off `nil?` by using `unless`:

```
var1 = hours.detect { |h| h.position > i && h.open == true }
unless var1
  hours.detect { |h| h.position >= 0 && h.open == true }
else
  var1
end
```

In this if, `hours.detect` is exact the same. You can extract it into method/lambda/proc. Here is method version:

```
def hourse_detect hours, &lam # `&` change block of code into variable(`proc` / `lambda`) OR variable(`proc` / `lambda`) into block of code
  hours.detect &lam #detect need block of code not `proc` / `lambda`
end
```

and your you can store blocks of code that exist between `{` and `}` (or `do` / `end`):

```
block1 =  proc { |h| h.position > i && h.open == true }
block2 =  proc { |h| h.position >= 0 && h.open == true }
```

Here is full code using above feautures:

```
def hourse_detect hours, &lam
  hours.detect &lam
end
block1 =  proc { |h| h.position > i && h.open == true }
block2 =  proc { |h| h.position >= 0 && h.open == true }
var1 = hourse_detect hours, &block1
unless var1
  hours_detect hours, &block2
else
  var1
end
```

`h.open == true`can be transformed into:

```
def opened? hour
  hours.open == true
end
```